# Reposting other peoples answers onto a personal blog

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, stackexchange

I enjoy a lot of the answers from this site.

But some of them I really like -- they are like little stories and I want to keep them around where I can find them and maybe where others might find them too.

Some particular examples

- https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/120013/2700
- https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/28554/2700

I was considering starting a blog on like tumblr or some such,
were I just copy-paste answers I like.
Giving links back to the the original answers and credits to the author.

I think CC SSA allows me to do that right?
Is there anything else I should be aware of, legally or for good manners?

Comment: You can also mark questions as favorites and you'll see them on the "favorites" tab on your profile page.  Alas, it's for question pages, not individual answers, but clicking on the star might be easier than reposting to your blog.

Comment: "I think CC SSA allows me to do that right?" It allows you to do that under certain conditions only. Of course they are not hard to meet (see the answer).

Answer (score 6):

I am not a lawyer. This is not legal advice. The references I chose may or may not be outdated. If you want to be safe you should contact a lawyer. And possibly the SE staff with the contact button at the bottom of the page.

From 
[Is it legal to copy Stack Overflow questions and answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/24611/352819), I will simply copy the [accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/24618/352819) as it seems to perfectly answer the legal portion of this question. This was in response to a site that copy-pasted a question together with all the answers/comments/... **without** attribution:

> Stack Overflow is licenced under [Attribution-Share Alike 3.0 Generic](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), which states:
>
> > **Attribution** — You must attribute the work in the manner specified by the author or licensor (but not in any way that suggests that they endorse you or your use of the work).
>
> I think it is pretty clear that they have failed to do this (or any attribution whatsoever). So IMO (and IANAL) no: this usage is not legitimate. But **within the terms of the cc-wiki agreement cited** re-use is fine.
>
> Edit: the cc-wiki licensing and [attribution policy](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) are also linked on every footer page like so.
>
> [image]
>
> If you click through to the [attribution policy](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) you will find the specifics:
>
> > So let me clarify what we mean by attribution. If you republish this content, we require that you:
> >
> > - **Visually indicate that the content is from Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Overflow, Server Fault, or Super User** in some way. It doesn’t have to be obnoxious; a discreet text blurb is fine.
> > - **Hyperlink directly to the original question** on the source site (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345)
> > - **Show the author names** for every question and answer
> > - **Hyperlink each author name** directly back to their user profile page on the source site (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/username)
> >
> > By “directly”, I mean each hyperlink must point directly to our domain in standard HTML visible even with JavaScript disabled, and not use a [TinyURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TinyURL) URL or any other form of obfuscation or redirection. Furthermore, the links must *not* be [nofollowed](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2005/01/preventing-comment-spam.html).

From a legal standpoint it seems like you *should* be fine *if you attribute* the stuff you copy.

---

From an ethical standpoint I would personally say that it might be a nice thing to write a comment to the person whose question/answer you want to copy and send them a link to your site in addition to attributing the content your copy. It might also be a nice thing to have a link to the blog/site/... here on Meta, for example in this discussion, in case someone is stumbling across your blog/site/... and wonders about whether this is legal or simply wants to check which questions/answers you copied.